# without downloadind an image from server get size of that image in nodejs

Tags: image, server, size, nodes, download

I have a server file which contains image URLs. I have less (or negligible disk space or ram).I don't want to download the image from there. I want to know image size or (maximum width or size of an image) in my API.

Appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server returns the `content-length` header, you could issue a HTTP HEAD request to just download the headers, and then retrieve the image size from the `content-length` header.

There is a gotcha - if your server uses content encoding to return images, you will get the compressed size of the image rather than the actual image size you require.

Comment: I have only list of URLs in server file. From  those URLs,  I want to know which image has maximum width and height

Comment: In that case, you only have two options - either download the image to retrieve its dimensions or create a new URL on your server that returns just the dimensions of the images.